# Sort IP's as sets of numerical octets (__not__ lexicographically)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm looking to sort entries in each row/cell of a specific column 'D' via IP address in ascending order. The entries are stored on a new line and have the associated protocol and port listed at the end of the IP, which I am not concerned about sorting just the 4 octets of the IP address. I feel this needs some sort of reg ex with a lambda function of some kind. Sometimes there might be a host name instead of an IP address.

Example dataframe would be:

```
ID    A     B     C     D
1     x     x     x     10.0.0.50/TCP/50
                        192.168.1.90/TCP/51
                        server1/TCP/80
                        10.0.0.9/TCP/78
2     y     y     y     192.168.3.90/UDP/53
                        10.0.4.10/TCP/65
                        10.0.3.4/TCP/34
                        host1/UDP/80
3     z     z     z     10.0.0.40/TCP/80
                        10.0.0.41/TCP/443
                        192.168.2.70/UDP/98
                        10.0.0.9/TCP/12
```

The desired output would be:

```
ID    A     B     C     D
 1    x     x     x     10.0.0.9/TCP/78
                        10.0.0.50/TCP/50
                        192.168.1.90/TCP/51
                        server1/TCP/80                   
 2    y     y     y     10.0.3.4/TCP/34
                        10.0.4.10/TCP/65
                        192.168.3.90/UDP/53
                        host1/UDP/80
 3    z     z     z     10.0.0.9/TCP/12
                        10.0.0.40/TCP/34
                        10.0.0.41/TCP/443
                        192.168.2.70/UDP/98
```

In order to achieve the above dataframe I initially combine row D using a groupby which works however the IP address are not in order:

```
df = df.groupby(['ID','A','B','C'], sort=False, as_index=False)['D'].apply('\n'.join)
```

It might be more efficient to combine and sort at the same time if possible rather than 2 separate commands??

Any thoughts much appreciated I have looked at a couple of examples however none seem to fit. Hopefully my explanation is clear enough, thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have your original DF, **before** grouping:

```
In [70]: df
Out[70]:
     ID  A  B  C                    D
0   1.0  x  x  x     10.0.0.50/TCP/50
1   1.0  x  x  x  192.168.1.90/TCP/51
2   1.0  x  x  x       server1/TCP/80
3   1.0  x  x  x      10.0.0.9/TCP/78
4   2.0  y  y  y  192.168.3.90/UDP/53
5   2.0  y  y  y     10.0.4.10/TCP/65
6   2.0  y  y  y      10.0.3.4/TCP/34
7   2.0  y  y  y         host1/UDP/80
8   3.0  z  z  z     10.0.0.40/TCP/80
9   3.0  z  z  z    10.0.0.41/TCP/443
10  3.0  z  z  z  192.168.2.70/UDP/98
11  3.0  z  z  z      10.0.0.9/TCP/12
```

**Option 1:** multi-index DF:

```
In [69]: (df.assign(x=df.D.replace(['/.*',r'\b(\d{1})\b',r'\b(\d{2})\b'],
    ...:                           ['',r'00\1',r'0\1'],
    ...:                           regex=True))
    ...:    .sort_values('x')
    ...:    .groupby(['ID','A','B','C'], sort=False, as_index=False)['D']
    ...:    .apply('\n'.join)
    ...:    .to_frame('D'))
    ...:
    ...:
Out[69]:
                                                           D
ID  A B C
1.0 x x x  10.0.0.9/TCP/78\n10.0.0.50/TCP/50\n192.168.1.9...
3.0 z z z  10.0.0.9/TCP/12\n10.0.0.40/TCP/80\n10.0.0.41/T...
2.0 y y y  10.0.3.4/TCP/34\n10.0.4.10/TCP/65\n192.168.3.9...
```

**Option 2:** regular DF:

```
In [75]: (df.assign(x=df.D.replace(['/.*',r'\b(\d{1})\b',r'\b(\d{2})\b'],
    ...:                           ['',r'00\1',r'0\1'],
    ...:                           regex=True))
    ...:    .sort_values('x')
    ...:    .groupby(['ID','A','B','C'], sort=False, as_index=False)['D']
    ...:    .apply('\n'.join)
    ...:    .reset_index(name='D'))
    ...:
    ...:
Out[75]:
    ID  A  B  C                                                  D
0  1.0  x  x  x  10.0.0.9/TCP/78\n10.0.0.50/TCP/50\n192.168.1.9...
1  3.0  z  z  z  10.0.0.9/TCP/12\n10.0.0.40/TCP/80\n10.0.0.41/T...
2  2.0  y  y  y  10.0.3.4/TCP/34\n10.0.4.10/TCP/65\n192.168.3.9...
```

---

the following might help to understand how does it work:

add a virtual column `x` with zero padded IP octets:

```
In [71]: df.assign(x=df.D.replace(['/.*',r'\b(\d{1})\b',r'\b(\d{2})\b'],
    ...:                           ['',r'00\1',r'0\1'],
    ...:                           regex=True))
    ...:
    ...:
Out[71]:
     ID  A  B  C                    D                x
0   1.0  x  x  x     10.0.0.50/TCP/50  010.000.000.050
1   1.0  x  x  x  192.168.1.90/TCP/51  192.168.001.090
2   1.0  x  x  x       server1/TCP/80          server1
3   1.0  x  x  x      10.0.0.9/TCP/78  010.000.000.009
4   2.0  y  y  y  192.168.3.90/UDP/53  192.168.003.090
5   2.0  y  y  y     10.0.4.10/TCP/65  010.000.004.010
6   2.0  y  y  y      10.0.3.4/TCP/34  010.000.003.004
7   2.0  y  y  y         host1/UDP/80            host1
8   3.0  z  z  z     10.0.0.40/TCP/80  010.000.000.040
9   3.0  z  z  z    10.0.0.41/TCP/443  010.000.000.041
10  3.0  z  z  z  192.168.2.70/UDP/98  192.168.002.070
11  3.0  z  z  z      10.0.0.9/TCP/12  010.000.000.009
```

sort DF by a virtual column `x`:

```
In [72]: (df.assign(x=df.D.replace(['/.*',r'\b(\d{1})\b',r'\b(\d{2})\b'],
    ...:                           ['',r'00\1',r'0\1'],
    ...:                           regex=True))
    ...:    .sort_values('x'))
    ...:
    ...:
Out[72]:
     ID  A  B  C                    D                x
3   1.0  x  x  x      10.0.0.9/TCP/78  010.000.000.009
11  3.0  z  z  z      10.0.0.9/TCP/12  010.000.000.009
8   3.0  z  z  z     10.0.0.40/TCP/80  010.000.000.040
9   3.0  z  z  z    10.0.0.41/TCP/443  010.000.000.041
0   1.0  x  x  x     10.0.0.50/TCP/50  010.000.000.050
6   2.0  y  y  y      10.0.3.4/TCP/34  010.000.003.004
5   2.0  y  y  y     10.0.4.10/TCP/65  010.000.004.010
1   1.0  x  x  x  192.168.1.90/TCP/51  192.168.001.090
10  3.0  z  z  z  192.168.2.70/UDP/98  192.168.002.070
4   2.0  y  y  y  192.168.3.90/UDP/53  192.168.003.090
7   2.0  y  y  y         host1/UDP/80            host1
2   1.0  x  x  x       server1/TCP/80          server1
```

Comment: This appears to be working the entries are sorted, however i'm only left with column D...

Comment: this is a useful answer thanks and it does work to a degree! However, in my scenario once I come to remove duplicates later in the script with `df['D'] = df['D'].apply(lambda s: '\n'.join(set(s.split('\n'))))` which I can only do after they have been combined, so I know they belong to X,Y or Z they get jumbled up again. Ideally I would need to sort them whilst in there combined state in one cell per row. Thanks for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: @Abob, you can easily get rid of duplicates _before_ combining / grouping IPs... Can you provide a __reproducible__ sample data set (with duplicates)? PS it doesn't make much sense to group / combine IP's beforehand as you would need to split them again in order to sort them properly

Comment: I have only given a small chunk of the dataset. There are instances where the same 'IP/tcp/port' in column D can be found in a row for X and Y, which is why they can only be removed as duplicates before being combined. I will try to sort another dataset to show you.